# Como Soluciono el Darle Clic al botón Igual sin Ningún Dato y que De Error, y error al no ingresar el segundo numero

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

```
private void btnCeroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+0);
}                                       

private void btnTresActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+3);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void btnUnoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+1);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void btnDosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+2);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void btnCuatroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+4);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void btnCincoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+5);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void btnSeisActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+6);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void btnNueveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+9);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void btnOchoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+8);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void btnSieteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.txtPantalla.setText(this.txtPantalla.getText()+7);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}      

private void btnDividirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    this.numero1=Float.parseFloat(this.txtPantalla.getText());
    this.operador="/";
    this.txtPantalla.setText("");        
}                                          

private void btnMultiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.numero1=Float.parseFloat(this.txtPantalla.getText());
    this.operador="*";
    this.txtPantalla.setText("");        
}                                        

private void btnSumaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    this.numero1=Float.parseFloat(this.txtPantalla.getText());
    this.operador="+";
    this.txtPantalla.setText("");
}                                       

private void btnRestaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.numero1=Float.parseFloat(this.txtPantalla.getText());
    this.operador="-";
    this.txtPantalla.setText(""); 

private void btnIgualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.numero2=Float.parseFloat(this.txtPantalla.getText());

    switch(operador){

        case "+":
            this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1+numero2));
            break;

        case "-":
            this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1-numero2));
            break;

        case "*":
            this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1*numero2));
            if(this.numero2==' '){
                this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1*numero1));
            }else{  
                this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1*numero2));
            }   
            break;

        case "/":
            if(this.numero2==0){
                this.txtPantalla.setText("No Se Puede Dividir en Cero");
            }else{
                this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1/numero2));
            }
            break;        

        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Una pregunta que solo contiene código es difícil de entender ¿Podrías dejar una breve explicación del problema?

Comment: Es una Calculadora Básica Realizada en Java con un JFrame y Botones.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y pon la explicación de que es tu aplicación, que se espera que haga y que es lo que te esta fallando.

Comment: Gracias @Cadeq Justamente Eso Puse en el Comentario, Es una Calculadora en Java, con las Funciones Básicas, Realice las Cuatro Operaciones Correctamente, Pero El Error es que Si No Se Han Ingresado Datos y le Damos Operar Nos Da Error, y El Otro Es que Si Ingresamos el Primer Numero Luego el Signo y Presionamos Operar Nos Da Error Porque No Se Ingresa el Segundo Valor a Operar.

Answer (score 0):

He visto que no tienes nada que controle si se rellenaron los dos valores o no.

Añade un condicional que se asegure que esten, si no, imprimira error en la consola y después volvemos a setear los numeros a null.

```
private void btnIgualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 this.numero2=Float.parseFloat(this.txtPantalla.getText());

 //Si no se setean los dos numeros, devolvemos error
 if(this.numero1 != null && this.numero2 !=null)
 {
    switch(operador){

       case "+":
           this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1+numero2));
           break;

       case "-":
           this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1-numero2));
           break;

       case "*":
           this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1*numero2));
           if(this.numero2==' '){
               this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1*numero1));
           }else{  
               this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1*numero2));
           }   
           break;

       case "/":
           if(this.numero2==0){
               this.txtPantalla.setText("No Se Puede Dividir en Cero");
           }else{
               this.txtPantalla.setText(sincero(numero1/numero2));
           }
           break;        

       default:
           break;
    }
}
else
{
    this.txtPantalla.setText("ERROR");

}

//Borramos numeros anteriores para que no interfieran con futuras operaciones
this.numero1=null;
this.numero2=null;
}
```

---

Con lo que me referia en el comentario es que editases la pregunta y pusieses el contenido del comentario en la pregunta.

Comment: Si Gracias, Solo que es Mi Primer Publicación y Al Editar mi Tiraba Errores al Publicar por Eso Ya No Lo edite y lo puse en comentario pero gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Por favor @Bladi_ST si la respuesta te ha solucionado el problema, marcala como correcta. Esto ayudara a futuros navegantes a saber que esta resolvió tu problema